# How to mass delete emails in iCloud

Tags: icloud

I have nearly 120,000 emails in iCloud. I can't go through and delete them 150 at a time because it would take too long. So how can I mass delete all these emails at once?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an email client you could mass delete by selecting all or configuring as a POP account and setting it to delete from the server, then remove it from the client.